# mit-scheme vim slimv: " read-error: no dispatch function defined for #\F"

Tags: lisp, scheme, mit-scheme, slimv

It's a very easy scheme function

```
(define member?
  (lambda (a lat)
    (cond
      ((null? lat) #f)
      (else (or (eq? (car lat) a)
                (member? a (cdr lat))
                ))
      )
    )
  )
```

However, when I pressed **,d** or **,F** in vim to run this function, there is an error

> /home/oo/tmp/t.scm:64   read-error: no dispatch function defined for
>   #\F
>
> Line: 4, Column: 21, File-Position: 64
>
> Stream: #<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /home/oo/tmp/t.scm" {AC84DA9}>

[image]

Comment: You can't execute Scheme code with a Common Lisp implementation. Here, it seems you're trying to run it on SBCL.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young , thank you. I read [this article](http://kovisoft.bitbucket.org/tutorial.html) to configure my vimrc, I don't know how to modify it to run mit-sheme file. I use ubuntu 12.04 as my laptop os.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chris already pointed out that you tried to use Scheme code with a Common Lisp swank server.
You need to run a Scheme swank server (e.g. `swank-mit-scheme.scm`, also included in Slimv).
Normally Slimv should autodetect MIT scheme on Linux without any tweaking in the `.vimrc`. For the autodetection to work properly you need MIT Scheme installed and the `scheme` command be available.

I suggest that you remove any Slimv related settings from your `.vimrc`. Then load the .scm in Vim and type this command:

`:echo SlimvSwankCommand()`

If Scheme was autodetected then this should print the command that runs the Scheme swank server (search for `swank-mit-scheme.scm` in the output). If the autodetection was unsuccessful then either you don't have the `scheme` command or Slimv did not find `swank-mit-scheme.scm`. In this case you need to tell Slimv the command to run the Scheme swank server. You can do in by adding a similar command to your `.vimrc`:

`let g:slimv_swank_cmd = '! xterm -e scheme --load /your-path-to/slime/contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm &'`

But do this only if autodetection fails. If you need some more assistance, please feel free to contact me, I'm the author of Slimv.

Comment: thank you very much. the command in my system is:! xterm -iconic -e "scheme" --load "/home/oo/.vim/bundle/slimv/slime/contrib/swank-mit-scheme.scm" &

Comment: why the slimv always put the right Parentheses **)** in a individual line?

Comment: It's called 'electric return' and may be disabled via `let g:paredit_electric_return=0`. The closing `)` in individual lines are gathered when you press `)` at the end of the line. Electric returns make linewise editing easier because inner lines of a form are balanced, you can swap lines easily, you don't have to worry about the extra unmatched parens. See [this](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/9479/openparen.gif) for a demo.

Comment: here is another question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14974738/vimcan-braces-auto-complete-in-java-file-as-elegant-as-lisp-file-with-slimv