# vim:Can braces auto complete in java file as elegant as lisp file with slimv?

Tags: vim, slimv

I have been use slimv for a long time, and found it's great in braces auto complete.

However, while I was editing java file, I tried to add this code in my vimrc

```
"Add the closing brace only at the end of the line
function! ConditionalPairMap(open, close)
  let line = getline('.')
  let col = col('.')
  if col < col('$') || stridx(line, a:close, col + 1) != -1
    return a:open
  else
    return a:open . a:close . repeat("\<left>", len(a:close))
  endif
endf
inoremap <expr> ( ConditionalPairMap('(', ')')
inoremap <expr> { ConditionalPairMap('{', '}')
inoremap <expr> [ ConditionalPairMap('[', ']')
```

Which is not smart as slimv does.

Is slimv support for java files?

Comment: No, slimv (actually paredit.vim) does not support java files. It only supports lisp-like files (lisp, clojure, scheme, racket). It is implemented for handling s-expressions.

Comment: @TamasKovacs Any advices for java programmer who uses vim as editor?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any advice for java. I'm the author of slimv, so I can help you in slimv-related questions. What I can tell you is that you cannot use slimv for java files, because it checks for the presence of well-formed s-expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Vim-autoclose](http://townk.github.com/vim-autoclose/). Possibly will work for Java.

I've been using it for a while now. It's works perfectly for PHP & JS. Only occasional problem when pasting code in. But easily solved by deleting a bunch of closing brackets at the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of plugins that provide auto-closing of braces and are probably more robust than your simplistic mapping. See the topic [Automatically append closing characters on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) for a discussion and list of plugins.

Comment: Actually, my vimrc setting above was copied from the web site you suggested:)

Comment: Then have a look at the plugins section. I personally use AutoClose by Karl Guertin (rarely, but haven't noticed any issues with it yet).